# Serving static files in Flask production

Tags: flask

I have the `static` folder in my `app` folder and that's where I have `js`, `css`, `images` etc. folders.

I reference them like this in my templates:

```
<script src="/static/js/main.js"></script>
```

and it works locally. But, when the app is published to production, I get a 404 for all static files. I'm new to flask so I guess I'm serving them wrong.
I don't have the `static` folder set as a designated static files folder anywhere in the app - is it done automatically if it's called 'static' or do I need to set it in code?

My project structure:

```
app/
├── static/
│   └── js/
|   |__ css/
├── templates/
│   └── index.html
└── __init__.py
application.py
```

application.py:

```
from app import create_app

application = create_app()
```

**init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from config import BaseConfig

def create_app():
    server = Flask(__name__)
    server.config.from_object(BaseConfig) # this is just for the secret key
    return server
```

Comment: What does *published to production* mean, how does it differ from your development setup? Can you include a tree-like representation of your app's file structure and the contents of files like __init__.py?

Comment: @Bert updated the code

Answer (score 2):

Flask automatically adds a static view that takes a path relative to the `$YOUR_APP/static` directory and serves it.

Typically you would include your js/css files in your templates like so:

```
{{ url_for('static', filename='main.js') }}
```

Comment: I've changed my hardcoded paths to this and still doesn't work when deployed. When I commit a change, it's automatically built on aws. Unfortunately, I don't have access to that part of aws. The static files are fetch OK on my dev server. Also, there's a dash app running inside this Flask app. It has it's own `assets` folder (same as static for Flask) and resources from that folder are served correctly, without a 404).

Answer (score 1):

First part of the solution was Bert's answer above which described how to correctly reference assets from the templates.

The other part I was missing was this:

```
server = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="", static_folder="static")
```

instead of what I had before:

```
server = Flask(__name__)
```

Adding `static_url_path` and `static_folder` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Bumping this up because I had the same issue when deploying to my RaspberryPi, and this fix seems undocumented.